# Argument of type '(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Application<Record<string, any>>'

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I'm working on an express project that uses typescript. I've set up controllers and routers, and have a method that wraps my controller logic in an error handler.

In my router.ts file, the post method throws the following error:

```
No overload matches this call.
The last overload gave the following error.
Argument of type '(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Application<Record<string, any>>'.
```

Sorry if this is a dumb question, but I'm new to typescript and these type errors, and I can't figure out what the fix is.

router.ts

```
import express from "express";
import { signup } from "../controller/controller.ts";

const authRouter = express.Router();

authRouter.post("/signup", signup);
```

controller.ts

```
import { NextFunction, Request ,Response } from "express";
import asyncHandler from "../utils/asyncHandler";

const signup = asyncHandler((req:Request, res:Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    res.status(200).json({ message: "signup" });
});

export { signup };
```

asyncHandler.ts

```
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from "express"

const asyncHandler = (fn:any) => (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  Promise.resolve(fn(req, res, next)).catch(next)
}

export default asyncHandler;
```

Comment: In file router.ts try add import { Request ,Response } from "express";

Answer (score 0):

i think you forgot to import Router in router.js

```
import { Router } from "express";
```

or forgot the implement route on the app.js

```
app.use("/api/auth", authRouter);
```